# How to add an option by clicking button on a page and have the option added to select tag in another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a chat-application where there are 2 pages. One page shows you default available chat-rooms in the select dropdown tag and the other allows you to make your own room.

What I am willing to do is to add the custom-room's name to the select-dropdown tag. I have tried to appendChild the room's name to select tag but it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null". Can anyone give me any suggestions to help me out?
Thanks for the read! Appreciate it...

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: Please add the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have a common state that is stored in a parent component, and when CustomRoom is ready, it sets the name, then RoomsDropdown is rerendered, because of the new property.

```
function Rooms () {
  const [customRoomName, setCustomRoomName] = useState()

  return (
    <>
      <RoomsDropdown customRoomName={customRoomName} />
      <CustomRoom onNameChange={setCustomRoomName} />
    </>
  )
}
```